# How to convert jmeter dashboard report to pdf

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

How to convert jmeter dashboard report to pdf

I'm unable to convert html report to pdf. plz suggest me the solution

Answer (score -1):

I tried many ways none of it works for Jmeter HTML report, other way was to zip all the artifacts and send over email but, that zip files contains .js files which get blocked by Gmail Yahoo

I written small code in Selenium to take screenshot (used Ashot API) of HTML report and sending over mail as attachment. Challenge here is headless mode of browser takes improper screenshot, so if you are on windows this can be achieved but as PNG, till now nothing works for PDF.

Answer (score -2):

C'mon, have you done at least basic research before asking? There are a lot of options, for example:

1. Print it to file, all modern browsers allow saving web content as PDF, check out [How to save a webpage as a PDF](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-save-a-webpage-as-a-pdf/)
2. There are online solutions like https://html2pdf.com/
3. There are offline solutions like http://www.pdflite.com/html-to-pdf/
4. There is [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) online results analysis service which allows saving load test report as PDF

Comment: Pardon! that's the basic feature, we can convert docs, html to pdf we have tools too. why i posted this doubt here is, in jmeter, html report is generating, when i try to convert to pdf not converting properly, data is not capturing properly. so is there any other way to convert to pdf is my doubt! If it is please update. Thanks.